# LocationManager Provider Types?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I was trying out the [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). It lists only 3 providers `GPS|NETWORK|PASSIVE_PROVIDER` in documentation.

I used `criteria` to get best possible location update.

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(0, 0, criteria, locationListener, null);
```

This works fine, but in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` function if I  check the provider used with `location.getProvider()` returns `fused`

The problem I have is that when I try to get last known location and use `getBestProvider`

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
```

The `getBestProvider` returns `gps` as provider and accuracy 42.475998 and if I manually enter `"fused"` the accuracy is 23.814

1- Why `getBestProvider` returns `gps` and not `fused` ?

2- So why there is no definition like `NETWORK_PROVIDER` for the `"fused"` provider? and it is not defined in `Android` documentation?

It is not suppose to be used directly? or it is because Google does not want us to use things which does not require google play services? :)

Thanks!

Comment: The roster of available location providers is determined by the device manufacturer (and, in the case of mock providers, by app developers). While the SDK only defines three that should be fairly commonplace, there is nothing stopping a device manufacturer from offering others, whether using a mix of tech (e.g., "fused") or completely different tech (e.g., Galileo, GLONASS).

Comment: Sure, but why `getBestProvider` can't return `fused`? because from documentation I assumed it will automatically return best, in my case it sems to be `fused`. Also because if I use `requestLocationUpdates` with `criteria` I get udpates from `fused` but if I use same `criteria` with `getBestProvider` I get `gps`. This seems wrong to me?

Comment: "but why getBestProvider can't return fused?" -- ask the device manufacturer. "because from documentation I assumed it will automatically return best, in my case it sems to be fused. " -- and on some other device, it might be something else. "This seems wrong to me?" -- `getBestProvider()` says "for the foreseeable future, what is the best possible provider", whereas `requestLocationUpdates()` with `Criteria` says "for the foreseeable future, give me location updates, using the best provider at the time given these criteria". Those could have different answers.

Comment: In the end, you are asking about implementation details from an un-stated version of the Android OS, as modified by an un-stated device manufacturer. Those details will vary by Android OS version and by manufacturer. The Android SDK is a contract setting out a floor of what is available on the device, a floor that we developers can rely upon across manufacturers (in theory). The implementation can do more than what the SDK makes available, just as a library can do more than what its API makes available.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please provide link to documentation where this is explained. Because `LocationManager` documentation, for `getBestProvider` it says `Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria.` and for `requestLocationUpdates` the `criteria` argument, it says `Criteria: contains parameters for the location manager to choose the appropriate provider and parameters to compute the location`
I ran `getBestProvider()` on `onLocationChanged` it NEVER returned `fused` meanwhile always received location in `onLocationChanged` was from `fused`. BTW. I am using LineageOS 14.1

Comment: "Please provide link to documentation where this is explained" -- I doubt that there is any such documentation. You are assuming that a one-time use of `Criteria` (`getBestProvider()`) will have the same results as an ongoing use of `Criteria` (`requestLocationUpdates()`). My point is that you have no basis for your assumption. "I am using LineageOS 14.1" -- the developers of that OS can do whatever they want. Do not assume that LineageOS is identical to the Android found on a Pixel 2, a Galaxy S8, or any of the OS editions on the ~10,000 Android device models.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am NOT using `getBestProvider()` one time. Everytime I receive a location update event, I check what is the current best provider. It NEVER returns `fused`. If it did what it should, it is bound to return `fused` at least sometimes if I ALWAYS receive updates from `fused` and they have better accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this specific issue, but as of Android 11 on some devices it appears `getBestProvider` can return `fused` and `getProviders()` can as well.

Notable, `PROVIDER_FUSED` was added as a constant in Api 31 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#FUSED_PROVIDER

Anyhow, I did some testing of `getProviders(true)` and `getBestProviders(Criteria(FINE_LOCATION), true)` that may prove useful:

```
MotoX Android 5.1
01-28 10:23:11.575 23263-23263 D: Providers: passive gps network 
01-28 10:23:11.575 23263-23263 D: Best Provider: gps

Galaxy S9 Android 9
2022-01-28 12:27:24.781 -0500 14129 14129 D: Providers: passive gps network
2022-01-28 12:27:24.781 -0500 14129 14129 D: Best Provider: gps

Galaxy A20 Androi 10
2022-01-28 12:34:53.038 -0500 23114 23114 D: Providers: passive network gps
2022-01-28 12:34:53.040 -0500 23114 23114 D: Best Provider: gps

Motorola Razr Android 11
2022-01-28 23:08:07.003 +0530 29548 29548 D: Providers: passive network gps
2022-01-28 23:08:07.004 +0530 29548 29548 D: Best Provider: gps

Pixel 3a XL Android 12
2022-01-28 12:31:47.386 -0500 20145 20145 D: Providers: passive network fused gps
2022-01-28 12:31:47.387 -0500 20145 20145 D: Best Provider: fused

Pixel 3 Android 12
2022-01-28 10:39:55.397 10580-10580 D: Providers: passive network fused gps 
2022-01-28 10:39:55.397 10580-10580 D: Best Provider: fused
```